# Subnet AzureFirewallSubnet is in use and cannot be deleted

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy a Azure Firewall using ARM templates. The template works fine during first deploy and creates a subnet (named AzureFirewallSubnet as required) in a existing virtual network as well as a Azure Firewall with a public IP. When trying to deploy the template a second time expecting the deployment to pass through without changes I get following error:

"*Subnet AzureFirewallSubnet is in use .../azureFirewallIpConfigurations/IpConf and cannot be deleted*"

Here is the detailed error message from the arm template deployment:

```
"details": [
  {
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Subnet AzureFirewallSubnet is in use by /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/<firewall-name>/azureFirewallIpConfigurations/IpConf and cannot be deleted.\",\r\n    \"details\": []\r\n  }\r\n}"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 12):

I was running into the same **InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted** issue when redeploying an unmodified ARM template, but I was able to resolve the issue by making two changes to the template.

1. Move the subnet definitions from the **resources** list to the **subnets** property of the virtual network.
2. Remove the subnets from the **dependsOn** list of your network interfaces (if you have them) and depend on the virtual network instead.

See the [virtualNetworks template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks?tabs=json) for more detail on the **subnets** property.

Once these changes were made, redeploying the template using the same parameter values became a no-op as you would expect.

Comment: Link to template is broken. Latest can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks?tabs=json

Answer (score 0):

this means you vnet contains a subnet called AzureFirewallSubnet and your template doesnt. So its trying to remove that vnet. Add this vnet to the template. Or delete it manually.

Comment: the subnet is created during the first deploy of the same template. The error appears on the second run without any changes of the template.

Comment: well, share the template in this case. nothing can be done if you think the templale is correct